# Migration Script Precedence

Tags: flyway

I'm investigating how Flyaway works to see if it's suitable for our upgrade and migration needs.

Can somebody tell me if Flyaway automatically handles precedence so that for example, if a table has a trigger, it creates the table before attempting to create the trigger, or is the user responsible to manually creating and ordering the actual SQL Statements required in each schema update?

Answer (score 0):

The latter - Flyway does not keep knowledge of the dependencies between database objects (as it's a very large and gnarly problem, and it's highly db-dependent). Which database do you use? A tool like [Redgate Schema Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/download) will generate the script with all the correct dependency orderings for you.

Comment: Hi Julia, thank you for your response. We already use Redgate SQL Compare but our lead dev believes that Flyaway will give the development team the ability to break our monolithic schema into smaller parts so that we can do smaller targeted updates to just those bits of schema tied to specific application functionality or feature changes.  I work in SQL admin and deployment so my concern is on database integrity and how this product actually alters the DB. I'm the guy who will need to fix it if a new tool screws up.